# How to turn on scrolling TextView Xamarin.Android C#

Tags: c#, scroll, xamarin.android, textview

Xamarin.Android how to turn on scrolling is simple for TextView, I've already poked everything and it just doesn't scroll

```
<TextView
    android:text=""
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:layout_width="354.0dp"
    android:layout_height="261.0dp"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:id="@+id/SamChatLabel"
    android:layout_marginLeft="18.0dp"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:textColor="#ff000000"
    android:layout_marginTop="96.0dp"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:verticalScrollbarPosition="right"
    android:isScrollContainer="true"
    android:overScrollMode="ifContentScrolls"
    android:fadeScrollbars="false"
    android:scrollbarSize="5dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:contextClickable="true"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a demo and it works well. If you want add a scrollbar you can add the code `android:scrollbars="vertical"` into the `TextView`.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8">
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">
    
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:background="#ff0000"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:maxHeight="40dp"
            android:text="add a long text to test"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```